# How to transition a path in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I transition (say, animate the creation) a path to give some visual effect. It could be creating the line/path from left to right. I tried something like.

I forked Mike's [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245), and added [like](http://bl.ocks.org/bsr203/5108692)

```
svg.append("path")
      .datum([])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);

  var t = svg.transition().duration(700);
  t.select('.line').attr('d', line(data));
```

it gives path error now, but I have some difficulty with updating gist and bl.ocks. But I remember it was working (but no animation).

How can I get an animated chart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think anyone describes it better than Mike Bostock himself: [Path Transitions](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/).

You can use variations of the examples in this tutorial to do different types of animations.  While his example is very much for transition a path to change in response to new data being added, you could just as easily use similar techniques to animate in response to changes in existing data -- or just a new series being added altogether.

If you can clarify exactly what kind of animation you're looking to do, I might be able to provide more detail towards achieving that end.

Comment: I would love to see some examples of how to transition/animate a path growing and shrinking in length as well as having a `marker-end` added. All the attempts I've made to do something like that ends up not animating anything at all.

Comment: I found this css trick using a dashed line , and transitioning the gap in the dash to 0. Haven’t tried it myself yet though.  https://codepen.io/MyXoToD/post/howto-self-drawing-svg-animation